# Adding Text to Clipboard on Click of ListView Column Header - C#

Tags: c#, listview, clipboard

Is there a an event for ListViews that are activated when one of the column headers are clicked on?  The plan was to add some text to the user's clipboard when they click on the column header.  Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See link below for the column header click event, where you would add some text to the user's clipboard.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.columnclick.aspx

Comment: When I put this line in, the event doesn't seem to work.

private void ColumnClick(object o, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
{
MessageBox.Show("Event Handled.";
}

Am I missing something?